# How an assignment problem is solved using greedy heuristic algorithm

Tags: greedy-algorithms, assignment-problem

Consider small instance of GAP involving 5 items and 2 resources with capacities 5 and 12 respectively. If we have cost matrix Cij and also consumption matrix bij with jobs vs resources, how can we calculate the objective function value using modified greedy heuristic algorithm when we have dual multiplier values alpha1 and alpha2 values?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE! I suspect you will need to [edit] your question to provide more context.  What is GAP?  What is the definition of a consumption matrix?  What is the "modified greedy heuristic algorithm" you have in mind, and what is the definition of its objective function?   It would help to define all terms/concepts and provide background to make the question understandable for others.  Where did you encounter this task?  Are you reading some textbook?  Can you provide a reference to what you're reading?

Comment: Or in other words, we don't have your textbook, we dont even know what it is, and we can't read your mind.